# Nodejs converts database time to UTC format without actually converting the date

Tags: sql, node.js, database, postgresql, pg-promise

In My database, I have following values for a column:

created_at: 2018-11-29 00:24:33.967124

But when I query this column to get its data in nodeJS, it returns following data:

created_at: 2018-11-29T00:24:33.967124Z

I do not know who is the culprit here, if it is nodejs/ postgres or timezone.

To explain more here is my query:

```
let query = "Select created_at from my_table limit 1";

let tableData = await runQuery(query);
console.log(tableData);
```

Output: 
[{ created_at: 2018-11-28T19:24:20.946Z }]

So I do not want node to convert/ format this data and retun the data as it is from database. How I can do that or what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the same. Timestamp with zero timezone is the same as timestamp without timezone. And Node.js driver will always give you timestamps with timezone.

```
const a = Date.parse('2018-11-29T00:24:33.967124Z');
const b = Date.parse('2018-11-29 00:24:33.967124');

console.log(a); //=> 1543451073967
console.log(b); //=> 1543451073967

console.log(a === b); //=> true
```